# VS Code how to format a few lines of SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, format, vscode-extensions

I have a main.go file with a sql query saved as a string.

```
    defer db.Close()
    id := 1 

    // format this query
    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT f_name, l_name from users WHERE id = ?", id)

    var fname, lname string
    err = row.Scan(&fname, &lname)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", fname, lname)
```

Is there a way to format that line?

Comment: have you tried to create a string variable?

Comment: @Progxy Yes but why would this matter? The point of the question is if there's a way to select some text and just format it as sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had the same problem. For me, the best solution is to move the SQL query to an [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) file and format it there. This also has the advantage of making more complex or larger SQL queries more readable.

For `*.sql` files can than be a plugin used. For example [Language PL/SQL](https://open-vsx.org/extension/xyz/plsql-language).

Here is an example:

**Excerpt of a repository (sqlite3,postgres,...)**

```golang
package repository

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    _ "embed"
)

//go:embed dml/selectUsers.sql
var selectUsers string

type Repository struct{
  sqlDB *sql.DB
}

func (r *Repository) GetUsers()([]*User,error){ 
    tx, err := s.sqlDb.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{ReadOnly: false})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to begin new transaction: %w", err)
    }
    defer tx.Close()

    selectedUsers, err := r.selectUsers(tx, selectUsers)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to select users: %w", err)
    }

    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to commit transaction: %w", err)
    }

    return selectedUsers, nil
}

func (r *Repository) selectUsers(tx *sql.Tx, query string, args ...interface{}) ([]*User,error) {
    stmt, err := tx.Prepare(insertCompany)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to prepare statement: %v", err)
    }
    defer stmt.Close()

    rows, err := stmt.Query(args...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to query statement: %v", err)
    }

    selectedUsers := make([]*User, 0)

    for rows.Next() {
        selectedUser := new(User)

        err = rows.Scan(
            &selectedUser.ID,
            &selectedUser.Surename, 
            &selectedUser.Familyname,
        )

        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to scan row: %v", err)
        }

        selectedUsers = append(selectedUsers, selectedUser)
    }

    return selectedUsers, nil
}
```

**dml/selectUsers.sql**

```sql
SELECT 
  id, 
  surename, 
  familyname
FROM
 users;
```